# How to parse page that uses HTML5 local storage?

Tags: node.js, parsing, local-storage

In advance sorry for my English)
I have a task - write a parser for site, but all his pages save entered data in HTML5 local storage. Its really to emulate click on images on pages and retrieve all variables values that was saved to data storage after this click? For example, using NodeJS + parser like jsdom (https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom)? Or i can use some alternatively technologies for this? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are trying to parse a website with lots of javascript. You can use phontom to simulate user behaviour. Consider you want to use node. Then you can use Node-Phontom to do that.

```
var phantom=require('node-phantom');
phantom.create(function(err,ph) {
  return ph.createPage(function(err,page) {
    return page.open("you/url/", function(err,status) {
      console.log("opened site? ", status);
      page.includeJs('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js', function(err) {
        //jQuery Loaded.
        //Settimeout to wait for a bit for AJAX call.
        setTimeout(function() {
          return page.evaluate(function() {
            //Get what you want from the page
            //e.g. localStorage.getItem('xxx');
        }, 5000);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

[Here is phontom.](https://www.npmjs.org/package/phantom)

[Here is node-phontom.](https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-phantom)